# Passing Connection string to other projects in .net-core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i recently started with .net-core and MVC so i start with kind of beginner question.

I made new project "Project.web" and added to same solution library project "Project.data". Now i want to pass database connection string to Project.data so i made this code in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var cc
            = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnString");
        services.AddDbContext<muniCVContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(cc));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();


    }
```

I referenced Project.data.Models namespace but it won't pass that connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project.data library create the examplesetting.json(You can use your custom setting.json) file.

examplesetting.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnString": "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set examplesetting.json properties. 
Select `Copy to Output Directory`  to `Copy always` and rebuild your project(Ctrl + Shift + B).

[image]

Change Configuration to your custom configuration and use it.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // create configuration by examplesetting.json
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddJsonFile("examplesetting.json");
    var configuration = builder.Build();
    
    // use examplesetting configuration to get the ConnString
    var cc = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnString");
    services.AddDbContext<muniCVContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(cc));
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```